# bootstrap alert-info text gets unreadable in mobile device when use with <a>

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, responsive-design, href

I am using a text with `<a></a>` in bootstrap class `alert-info` and it works find for big screen but when i open that page from mobile device or i make the window smaller then the text gets unreadable. But if i use this without `<a></a>` tag then its ok.

```
    <br>
    <div>
          <a class="alert alert-info" href="/process/info/"><?php echo $oFontawesome->icon(array('icon'=>'external-link')).' '._('This case contains an course info that you need to pay. Please register your payment through "Payments".');?></a>
    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `.alert` in `<a>`, because `<div>` has the attribute `'display:block'` but `<a>` has not.
if you really want to use `.alert` in `<a>`, you need add a style for the element:

```
<a class="alert alert-info"
   style="display:block">
      This case contains an course info that you need to pay. Please register your payment through "Payments"
</a>
```

or you can put the `<a>` tag inside `<div>`:

```
<div>
  <a class="alert alert-info">
        This case contains an course info that you need to pay. Please register your payment through "Payments"
  </a>
</div>
```